# Java Lottery Numbers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am making a little program that is like a lottery. The point is that there will be 7 generated numbers, different from each other (except the seventh number). My code is this :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class LotteryNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random generator = new Random();
    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int index = 1;
    int luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49);

    while (index < 7) {
        if (seen.contains(luckyNumber)) {
            continue;
        }
        seen.add(luckyNumber);
        System.out.println("Number " + index + ": " + luckyNumber); 
        index++;
        luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49);
    }
    System.out.println("Bonus Number :" + generator.nextInt(49));
}

}
```

As you can see I have made a set called seen where all the numbers that are generated are stored. However, the program doesn't work properly as the loop stops unexpectedly sometimes. What is my mistake?

Thank you. :)

Comment: What do you mean by stopping unexpectedly? Does the program throw any exception?

Comment: Why use the `continue`? Change your `if` to `if (!seen.contains(luckyNumber))` and put the code inside the if block except for the lucky number assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the `if`, you'll get stuck in an endless loop - no new number is generated, and in each iteration of the loop the same number is evaluated, and the `if` is entered.

One way to solve this is to generate another number in such a case:

```
while (index < 7) {
    if (seen.contains(luckyNumber)) {
        luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49); // here
        continue;
    }
    seen.add(luckyNumber);
    System.out.println("Number " + index + ": " + luckyNumber); 
    index++;
    luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49);
}
System.out.println("Bonus Number :" + generator.nextInt(49));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you enter an infinite loop when the Set contains the lucky number chosen, as you never reset `luckyNumber`

```
while (index < 7) {
    if (seen.contains(luckyNumber)) {
        continue;
    }
```

This should probably be:

```
while (index < 7) {
    if (seen.contains(luckyNumber)) {
        luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49);
        continue;
    }
```

You should look into how to use the debugger as well, you most likely would have recognized the error right away by stepping through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, my simplified method:

```
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<Integer>();

while (seen.size() < 7) {
    int luckyNumber = generator.nextInt(49);
    seen.add(luckyNumber);
}
System.out.println(seen);
```

It should work.